# Does asp.net setting affect classic asp (IIS 6 settings)

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, iis-6, settings

My company has some classic asp sites and developing new sites in asp.net, and everytime we create a new site in IIS 6 all the sites go down for a couple of seconds. So I'm thinking of changing the default value of the ASP.NET version to 2.x since that is what we're developing and I'm wondinger if these settings somehow affect the classic asp sites that are running on same IIS.

All of them are asp.net 1.1 versioned right now but we have to get around this all-sites-down everytime we add a new site to IIS.

Any warnings? Anything I need to know etc?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All sites reset when you change the version of a site. Therefore, it is a good idea to change the default to the one you add the most.

The default setting will not affect any existing sites, .net, classic or otherwise.

The only issues you may have is that you cannot run a 1.1 virtual app within a 2.0 site.

Also, you cannot run different versions in the same app pool. Therefore you should change the default app pool at the same as changing the default version.

As an aside, I have read of some command line options and other setting that mean you can change the version of a site without causing all of iis to reset. However, I have not managed to do this personally.

Comment: Hi! And thanks for the answer. 

We only run .net 2.x sites and classic asp sites, no .net 1.1 at all. 

As you said I should change the default and thats what I was thinking, Running the aspnet_regiis -i command in the .net framework 2.0 folder should change ALL sites to .net 2.0 but I just want to be 100% sure that no classic asp sites go down and stops working.

Comment: Changing the .net version changes which binaries are used to handle the .net code. It will not affect what is used to handle any classic asp code. That will still be handled by inetsrv/asp.dll as before.

Answer (score 1):

Running a classic site along site a .Net site in the same app pool should be fine and you shouldnt see any down time in the IIS when you upload a new version to the server.

You will find the server pause for a few seconds if you change the config of any app pool or if you change over the .Net version that is running in a site, all sites running in that app pool will be reset as the app pool resets.

My recomendation would be to create 2 App pools one for your new .Net 2.0 sites and one for the old classic sites, this will also help out if you are undergoing development as although unlikely it is possable to write code to complete crash the app pool.

The only thing to remembger is that each app pool as a small memory overhead about 3-5MB so if you nmake an app pool for each site and host a large number of site you can very quickly run out of RAM.