# Will running aspnet_regiis.exe -ir create any problems?

Tags: asp.net, iis, settings, aspnet-regiis.exe

I've asked a question about changing the version of .Net sites in the IIS. If it affects classic asp sites etc (See [Does asp.net setting affect classic asp (IIS 6 settings)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847406/does-asp-net-setting-affect-classic-asp-iis-6-settings))
And that seems fine. So my follow-up question is, will running this command get me fired? What it does is changing the default value (and all existing?) of the .net version to 2.0.

This wont affect any of the .net sites since they're allready versioned to 2.0.
The classic asp pages needs to get its app pools updated so its functionoal with 2.0 but may I run into any other troubles?

I've tried doing this on a test environment and no sites whet down during the installation period (from the command) but I did not have any classic asp sites or any .net sites running though (which I should test, come to think about it) but may something else break?

Is this command doing anything else? We have some very large sites running and we cannot have downtime periods so I need to be 100% sure that this command is safe. Since all sites go down everytime we change a new sites .net version number we need to get this fix live asap.

Any good ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

long time since I asked, but Dror, thanks for your edit. I'll be sure to try it.

I actually found a solution to this problem some months ago.

You can export a sites configuration, and you get a XML file, edit this file and set the site name etc to something (like dev1). Then you import this and you got yourself a new site with .net pre-configured. Just make sure you change the name and other things that cannot be the same as another site (like host things, cant remember exactly what parameters there were) because that would cause a problem I guess.

Happy iising

Answer (score 1):

This should not cause any side affect as it relates to what the IIS does with .NET pages (e.g. aspx extensions).
Since the classic asp pages are not handled by the .NET extensions in the IIS I can see no reason to worry.
**EDIT:**
According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28VS.80%29.aspx) you can use an option

> -norestart - inhibits the restart of the World Wide Web Publishing Service after installing or updating ASP.NET script maps. If you do not use this option, all application pools are recycled.

so you can see from that application pools **will** be recycled.

Comment: Hi there!
Thanks for the reply.

Well, it shouldnt affect what happens with the classic asp sites no, but the IIS might do something bad in general? ie restart the iis, crash app pools since they're set to .net 1.1? And if they do crash, sites will go down?

Is the app pools explicit set to function only with one version or its only that you cannot run different versions in the same pool?

I dont know, I just want to be a 100% sure that the sites will remain online.